# How to write text inside a function in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to comment some functions that have lots of line of code. So I would like to write some paragraphs **inside** the function.

Example:

````
```{r}
sample.fn <- function(x) {
x <- x+1
x <- x+2
#...
```
````

*Here I would like to write some text. Maybe write some equations:*

```
$$  
\begin{align}   
x &= x + 1\\  
\end{align*}  
$$
```

*And then continue with the function*

````
```{r}
x <- x + 3
return(x)
}
```
````

Thanks

Comment: Not comments (as in "# comment"), but text like full paragraphs or equations. Pretty much all the other content of a .Rmd that is not code.

Comment: By far the easiest way would be to have a "hidden" chunk where you define the full function (`echo = FALSE`), then for the parts where you display the function code, use `eval = FALSE`.

Comment: @Gregor, I think you should post that as answer.  `knitr` doesn't have the same operation as Knuth's original "web" system, which would allow this easily

Comment: @BenBolker That is true, but I'd argue if you have to explain a function half-way as you define it, your function is probably too long and needs to be split into smaller pieces :)

Comment: sorry -- that wasn't meant to be a criticism, just a description ...

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment to an answer: I don't believe there's a way to break up an evaluated chunk, but you can create the illusion with some sleight-of-chunk. Include one chunk that is not printed (i.e., `echo = FALSE`) that includes your full function definition, and then include as many chunks as you want with `eval = FALSE` that repeat the code but with as many breaks in the chunk as you like.